# How to input email and password for PayPal using Selenium2Library?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to input email and password into PayPal (sandbox mode) using my Robot Framework script. This is a snippet of my code:

```
input text  login_email  ${email}  
input text  login_password  ${password}
```

`login_email` is the *name* of the *input* field for the email and `login_password` is for the password.

I am passing the email in the `${email}` argument and the password in the `${password}` argument.

This doesn't seem to work for some reason. I keep getting this error:

> InvalidElementStateException: Message: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

The email and password field for PayPal are generated upon the loading of the page. Can that be a reason why they are not accessible? Can anybody help me identify what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: trying giving it a wait. It might look like its loaded but to the driver its not. Just add a `Sleep  2s` above the two `input text` keywords and see if it works that time.

Comment: Goralight This is the best way and @Shehzaan Ansari  check your complete page load time and add sleep time.

Comment: @Goralight I added `Sleep  4s` and it loads the page fine with all the input fields but doesn't do anything after that. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Maybe try specifying that it is a name you are trying to interact with? `input text | name=login_email | ${email}`

Answer (score 1):

As Correctly said by Ofer Steinberg , try to find the XPATH manually
Also, add a wait point until that item is visible and the  enter name and password
as many times item is present and hidden due to which it says item not interactable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have there a 'not constant' id (or similar..).
I had this problem, and the solution was to change the input path from id to xpath.
Moreover, try to inspect the paths manually in 'guest mode' (I guess you using chrome), it should show that page source more accurately since the selenium running by it.